# How to write Rspec for basic Show, Create, Destroy, Edit methods in rails (with or without FactoryGirl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I have a basic user_controller.rb file like this:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @user = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end      
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

 def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy
  redirect_to action: 'index'
 end

 private
  def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :key, :desc)
  end
end
```

This is my (model) user.rb file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name,    presence: true
  validates :key,     uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :desc,    presence: true
end
```

And created a factories.rb file (in the specs folder):

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do
   name "TestUser"
   key "TKey"
   desc "TestDescription"
  end
end
```

I tried several ways to make the specs work but I can't because of the confusing syntax.

The only one which worked was (for the 'C' in the CRUD operations, the below file is user_controller_specs.rb):

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

RSpec.describe UserController, :type => :controller do
 let(:temp) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

 describe "POST create" do
  it "should redirect back to the index page" do
     post :create, :user => { :user => temp }
     expect(get: user_url(subdomain: nil)).to route_to(controller: "user", action: "index")
  end
 end
end
```

I skimmed through several tutorials to find what should be the correct approach for CRUD operations but didn't got any simple to understand specs. I am trying to write these in the specs/controllers folder but these are giving errors.  What should be the correct syntax to write the specs?

PS: I'am new to Ruby/Rails and trying to write test cases with Rspec and FactoryGirl. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
 Maybe I framed the question wrongly... I'm more interested in the syntax part. If I get to know an example how to write one, I'll be able to write others by changing some tiny bits of logic here and there.... Let's say I have a basic test case just to see whether updating a user details is not returning an error because of validations, how should I write it with (or without) Factory Girl gem?

Comment: There are plenty of resources online demonstrating Rspec syntax and examples. You could Google `rspec controllers`. For starters, check out [Better Specs](http://www.betterspecs.org/), [Relish](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs), or even some articles like from [Everyday Rails](https://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty broad question, but in any kind of test, you want test whatever use cases you have available to you. Example--are there different paths users might follow from hitting a specific controller action.

So you want your test to cover the basics. When you hit the create action, is a user actually created? If the relevant params are missing, is an error thrown? Use cases will drive your expectations.

With rspec controllers specifically, you'll use the appropriate verb and the name of the action, and pass it whatever parameters are necessary.

`post :create, :user => { :user => temp }`

That basically says, "do a post request to my create an action and pass it the parameters inside these curly braces."

After running that rspec gives you access to the response. You can always log the response after a controller request to help you debug the situation: `p response`.

You'll follow up each type of request with an expectation. The expectation should answer the question: "What did I expect hitting this action to *do*?" If you were, for instance, hitting the user update action and passed a param to change the user's age to 21, your expectation might be something like:

`expect(user.age).to eq(21)`

A great resource is the rspec documentation on relish. https://relishapp.com/rspec

"How to" do a broad general thing is a tough question to answer like this. My advice would be to try to actually test one, log the failure case, and post those logs in a new question and people on SO can help you work through testing a particular action you're struggling with.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the elaborate explanation. Maybe I framed the question wrongly... I'm more interested in the syntax part. If I get to know an example how to write one, I'll be able to write others by changing some tiny bits of logic here and there.... Let's say I have a basic test case just to see whether updating a user details is not returning an error because of validations, how should I write it with Factory Girl gem?

Comment: FactoryGirl is for creating the data for the test. So factory girl is a different issue. How to create the data should be a new question. I usually test validations in model specs. And you need to test all the cases. Write tests to make sure the creation doesn't happen when the validation fails and then a test where everything is present and creation occurs. If you want to make a question about testing validations I'll post an example there. I think these are separate questions for SO purposes. One is about how to use factory girl and one is about how to test validations.